# Implement scroll based events in DTM

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I am struggling with implementing scroll event in DTM. I know we can do it using enter vieport option on div but I do not want to implement it that way.
I would like to use window.scroll functions (preferably).

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

You should start with page load rule where you can paste custom js script.

Like:

```
if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - .50*jQuery(document).height()) {
 if (passed <50) {  
 passed+=25;
 _satellite.track('Scroll50'); 

 }
 }
```

then you can prepare direct call rule with string: Scroll50
and you are ready to setup analytics.

Hope it helps.

Comment: One follow up question, so when I am testing it my local I don't have jQuery so it gives errors. Is there any way we can point to jQuery JS using javascript?

Comment: you can ensure jQuery presence using page load rules via DTM. Also you are able to add jQuery from console in your browser.